# More efficient in Android app? Database or Objects

Tags: android, database, performance, pojo, memory-efficient

I have 30 objects, each instance consisting of 7 string fields and a small bitmap.
These objects will be destroyed and recreated daily.
In my android app, would it be more efficient to write and read this data from a db? or to simply create a new class and create the 30 instances and store them in an array?
Memory efficient/performance/etc.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to write boilerplate code for database you can save your objects in `JSON` or `XML` format as files.

You got two ways:

1. Store in filesystem using serialization to store and deserialization to read
2. Store in `JSON` or `XML` natively and write converter between your class and needed data format

Database is good solution, because `SQLite` in Android is real fast and so on. But if you will want to change structure of table you will have to write `ALTER TABLE` queries in `onUpdate()` method of [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) and other troubles.

So I would recommend to use `XML` or `JSON` to store data.

**Upd**

Also, you can mark your custom data class as serializable, store values in ArrayList or other structure and serialize it to store, then deserialize to read.

Comment: Thanks Artem. Going with storing in an XML

Answer (score 0):

For a limited number of object I think you are batter with `Object` representation and storing them in an `ArrayList`. DB design for a large number of entries.

But if the data needs to be saved for all day you are risking in loosing it by a `GC` if you leave it in memory, in that case you have no option but to store it in the DB.

where are you getting this data from?

Answer (score 0):

Write the items to a database because they need to be persistent, if only for 24 hours.

You should store the image files in your *Internal Storage* sandbox and reference them by filename in the database because it is usually inefficient to store even the smallest `Bitmap` blobs in the database.